# How to refuse transfer due to family issues?

Tags: management, india, relocation

I am working with a Insurance company located at Mumbai. Recently have received a transfer letter.

I am a single parent of twin daughters that are studying in last year. I am not in a position to leave them alone and take a transfer as their responsibility solely depends on me, neither I am in a position to move on with them at a location as that is totally new and may hamper my daughter's education as well as have psychological impact.

I don't want to get transferred yet continue the job at the current location.Either transfer or resign are the two options.

As my age is 55 years, I can't afford to lose the job after working for 10 years with the said company.

Please advice so that I get my transfer cancelled and I can continue with the same location. Thanks

Comment: @David K: I don't think its a dup of that question. This question deals with a MNC that may have different rules and policies as a result.

Comment: What is an MNC?

Comment: @Mister Positive: A multinational corporation. Different rules/laws that govern MNC then those that govern say U.S. Based businesses.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech I'm with you. [tag:india] questions are rarely dupes of non-[tag:india]  questions, because things are so very different there.

Comment: Now after my request to HR Head regarding inability to relocate either with family or alone to Cuttack , they have given me a option to relocate to another location to Goa. Kindly advice as it's a dead end for me . Thanks and regards

Answer (score 1):

The only real answer that can be given here is to contact HR and find out all your possible options and outcomes.

Make sure you know all the facts before moving forward with any decision.

1. Is there anything in your contract that would require you to transfer.
2. Is there any legal reason to deny a transfer. (IE: Kids in school who have special needs)
3. Find out if there is grounds to postpone a transfer rather than flat out refusing.
4. ...

I am sure there are more variables but the ones I listed are the first ones that came to mind.

There is a lot to consider when making a chose on something like this.

this link gives some context with employee rights when [working for multinational employers.](https://www.eeoc.gov/facts/multi-employees.html)
Though it mentions transfers it does not go into great detail. Its still a starting point if you have not found one.

Keep in mind this link is only related to U.S. Law. The link was given for context. You may need to research the laws the country you are currently in.

Comment: The link you provided only applies to the US and its citizens; the OP has clearly stated they are in India.

Comment: @David K. Yes thats is correct. I did mention the different laws/rules in the comment section in the OPs question but I will add it to my answer for clarification.